# Asp.Net dropdownlist showing blank after postback when page idle

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have 2 dropdownlists on my page. One for activity and one for sub activity. When the activity dropdownlist changes I retrieve the values for the sub activity dropdownlist . I am using a updatepanel for the second dropdownlist and the trigger is set to the first dropdownlist. This is working magicly until I leave the page to idle for a while 1-2min max. When I change the value for the activity dropdownlist(the trigger) it causes a full postback and the items for the second dropdownlist does not get populated.

Here is my code below.

Aspx

```
   <div class="form-line">
    <label>Activity</label>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActivity" required="required" CssClass="chosen-select" runat="server" Width="200px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedActivity_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false">
    </asp:DropDownList>

</div>
<div class="form-line">
    <label>Sub Activity</label>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlActivity" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubActivity" runat="server" Width="200px" required="required" CssClass="chosen-select" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CausesValidation="false">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>
```

Code behind

```
 [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class MyEstimatesAdd : WebPart
    {
        static string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        ChronoLogDataContext dc = new ChronoLogDataContext(connStr);
        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing Performance Profiling on a farm solution
        // using the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
        // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
        // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        public MyEstimatesAdd()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Page.Request.QueryString["Issue_ID"] != "" && Page.Request.QueryString["Issue_ID"] != null)
                {
                    Int64 issueid = Int64.Parse(Page.Request.QueryString["Issue_ID"]);
                    string sCurrentUserEmail;
                    SPUser cuser = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context).CurrentUser;

                    sCurrentUserEmail = cuser.Email;
                    dc = new ChronoLogDataContext(connStr);

                    var resource = (from r in dc.RESOURCEs
                                    where r.Email == sCurrentUserEmail
                                    select r).FirstOrDefault();

                    ddlActivity.DataSource = (from a in dc.ACTIVITY_CATEGORies
                                              select a).ToList();

                    ddlActivity.DataValueField = "Activity_Category_ID";
                    ddlActivity.DataTextField = "Description";
                    ddlActivity.DataBind();
                    ddlActivity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
                }


            }
        }

        //RUN AGAIN PRIMARY SET
        protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int hours;
            if (!int.TryParse(txtHours.Text, out hours))
            {
                throw new SPException("Hours must be a numeric value");
            }
            string sCurrentUserEmail;
            SPUser cuser = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context).CurrentUser;
            sCurrentUserEmail = cuser.Email;
            dc = new ChronoLogDataContext(connStr);
            var resource = (from r in dc.RESOURCEs
                            where r.Email == sCurrentUserEmail
                            select r).FirstOrDefault();
            Int64 issueid = Int64.Parse(Page.Request.QueryString["Issue_ID"]);
            decimal time = decimal.Parse(hours + "." + ddlMinutes.SelectedValue.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            ESTIMATE estimate = new ESTIMATE { Activity_ID = int.Parse(ddlActivity.SelectedItem.Value), Date_Captured = DateTime.Now, Estimated_Time = time, Features = txtFeatures.Text, Issue_ID = issueid, Resource_ID = resource.Resource_ID, Sub_Activity_ID = int.Parse(ddlSubActivity.SelectedItem.Value) };
            dc.ESTIMATEs.InsertOnSubmit(estimate);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            Close_Save();
        }
        protected void Close_Save()
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["IsDlg"] != null)
            {
                context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup()</script>");
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.End();
            }


        }

        protected void SelectedActivity_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int activityid = int.Parse(ddlActivity.SelectedItem.Value);
             dc = new ChronoLogDataContext(connStr);
             var subactivities = (from s in dc.ACTIVITY_SUBCATEGORies
                                  where s.Activity_Category_ID == activityid
                                  select s).ToList();
             ddlSubActivity.Items.Clear();
             ddlSubActivity.DataSource = subactivities;
             ddlSubActivity.DataValueField = "Activity_SubCategory_ID";
             ddlSubActivity.DataTextField = "Description";
             ddlSubActivity.DataBind();
             ddlSubActivity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
             UpdatePanel1.Update();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both drop down lists within the same `UpdatePanel` or each in their own `UpdatePanel`, like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlActivity" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="form-line">
            <label>Activity</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActivity" required="required" CssClass="chosen-select" runat="server" Width="200px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedActivity_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class="form-line">
            <label>Sub Activity</label> 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubActivity" runat="server" Width="200px" required="required" CssClass="chosen-select" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CausesValidation="false">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Just tried it. Still same problem. It is only happening in Chrome. In IE its working fine. Really odd.

Comment: Is there anything in the Chrome Developer Tools console when it "breaks"?

Comment: No nothing. I hope I am doing it right. Opening page > Ctrl + Shift + J. A window pops up with tabs warnings,errors etc. Change dropdownvalue. No message in errors, warning or debug tabs.

Comment: For Chrome, Ctrl + Shift + I for Chrome Developer Tools; Ctrl + Shift + J is for JavaScript console only, since we are dealing with server-side logic in partial page post backs the main developer tools will/might be more helpful.

Comment: Tried Ctrl+Shift+I. Same results.

Comment: This is the bane of `UpdatePanel`s, when they work they are great, when they don't they are a nightmare to debug. Are you interested in a solution that does not use `UpdatePanel` or are you determined to get this working, as is?

Comment: What solution do you have? I have used fullpage postbacks so far because of this problem.

Comment: I can think of two alternatives: are you familiar with ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods or the CascadingDropDown in the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit?

Comment: Thank you for your sugestion.i read up a bit about both and it looks exactly what im looking for.